# How to know that the user pressed back in Card IO scanner mode ?

Tags: android, back, card.io

I wish to know if the user has pressed back in card.io scan to react accordingly in my activity. Can I do that ? Does card.io send an intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calling activity's `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` method, `resultCode` will have a value of `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`.

The 'Sample Code' section of the [README](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK) has more detail. Also, check out the [sample app](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/tree/master/SampleApp).

Comment: that is good to know. My issue was there because I set the flag noHistory to true for the activity calling Card.io during a debbuging and forgot to remove it :) 

Thanks anyway !